# Permutations with Repeated Letters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This question is taken from *A First Course in Probability (8e)* by Ross.

> How many different arrangements can be formed from the letters PEPPER?

I understand that there are $6!$ permutations of the letters when the repeated letters are distinguishable from each other. And that for each of these permutations, there are $(3!)(2!)$ permutations within the Ps and Es. This means that the $6$$!$ total permutations accounts for the $(3!)(2!)$ internal permutations. Then, the explanation in the text states that there are $\frac{6!}{(3!)(2!)} = 60$ possible letter arrangements of the letters PEPPER.

I don't understand this last part. I thought that since the internal permutations were accounted for the total possible letter arrangements would be the $1 - \frac{(3!)(2!)}{6!}$. Can someone please explain the logic behind the last part? Thank you.

Comment: $1-\frac{3!2!}{6!}$ is not a *number* of permutations.

Comment: I was not applying a permutation rule as I did not know which one to apply. How do you decide which one to apply here?

Comment: "Number of arrangements" by default means a value >= 1, even 0! = 1, only way to find is either manually or apply combination and permutations, there's no way for probability to be applied here

Answer (score 7):

Let's do it smaller with $PPE$. If the letters $P$ are given an index then there are $3!=6$ possibilities:

- $P_1P_2E$
- $P_2P_1E$
- $P_1EP_2$
- $P_2EP_1$
- $EP_1P_2$
- $EP_2P_1$

If the indices are taken away then $P_1P_2E$ and $P_2P_2E$ both become $PPE$. It appears that possibility $PPE$ has been counted $2!=2$ times. To repair this we must divide by $2!$ and get $3$ as answer. This agrees with the fact that there are $3$ possibilities:

- $PPE$
- $PEP$
- $EPP$

Likewise in $PEPPER$ every permutation is originally counted $3!2!$ times, so we must divide $6!$ by $3!2!$ to repair.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we want to form a permutation of $P_1E_1P_2P_3E_2R$.

We know there are $6!$ ways to do this, since the letters are all distinct, but we could also do this by

1) forming a permutation of $PEPPER$, which can be done in, say, x ways;

2) assigning subscripts to the P's, which can be done in $3!$ ways; and then

3) assigning subscripts to the E's, which can be done in $2!$ ways.

Therefore $6!=x(3!)(2!)\;,$ so $\displaystyle x=\frac{6!}{3!2!}$

---

Here is an alternate way to do this:

1) Choose the places for the E's, which can be done in $\dbinom{6}{2}$ ways.

2) Next choose the place for the R, which can be done in $\dbinom{4}{1}=4$ ways.

The P's must go in the remaining places, so we get $\dbinom{6}{2}\cdot4$ permutations of PEPPER.

Answer (score 0):

**Main question as posted by the OP**

> How many different arrangements can be formed from the letters PEPPER?

**Main Doubts:**

1. `6!`
   permutations of the letters when the repeated letters are distinguishable from each other
2. And that for each of these permutations, there are `(3!)(2!)`
   permutations within the Ps and Es
3. This means that the `6 !`
   total permutations accounts for the `(3!)(2!)`
   internal permutations. Then, the explanation in the text states that there are `6!(3!)(2!)=60`
4. I don't understand this last part. I thought that since the internal permutations were accounted for the total possible letter arrangements would be the `1−(3!)(2!)6!`

**Answering all the points to clarify most of the doubts:**

5. For unique 6 letters  answer would be `6! or 6P6` (Permutation) or calculate using Combination `(6c1 * 5c1 * 4c1 * 3c1 * 2c1 * 1c1)`, why arrangement is different from mere selection since order of selection is also important and that's we can deduce the same using Combination as shown above
6. `3!` for P and `2!` for E comes into the picture since order of selection mentioned above lose its significance, you cannot distinguish which P or which E thus there's a reduction in the total number of arrangements, which were there for the unique letters and that's why this division becomes important and thus the solution is `6!/(3! * 2!)`
7. Now, why it can't be `1−(3!)(2!)6!`, since we aren't looking for probability and anything that says number of ways or arrangements has to be `>= 1`
8. Now let's see how do we arrive at the final solution `6!/(3! * 2!)`, in the `PEPPER`, out of 6 letters there are `3P, 2E and 1R`, how can we select 3 slots out of 6 for 3 P, `6C3`, why not `6P3`, that's because you can't arrange `3 P's` in different ways, now remaining places are 3, so we can select two places for E as `3C2` and finally only 1 place remaining for R, so the solution would be `6C3 * 3C2 * 1C1` = `6!/(3!*3!) * 3!/(2!*1!) * 1!` = `6!/3!*2!`
9. Let's consider same thing other way we consider 2 E first, then 3 P and last R, `6C2 * 4C3 * 1C1` = `6!/(4!*2!) * 4!/(3!*1!) * 1!` = `6!/3!*2!`
10. Let's take another way, take R first then P then E, `6C1 * 5C3 * 2C2` = `6!/(5!*1!) * 5!/(3!*2!) * 2!/(2!*0!)` = `6!/3!*2!`

Therefore which ever way you choose the answer remains same and its easy to deduce