# How to find the number of options to arrange similiar objects?

Tags: probability

The probability of blue ball is **0.5** and the probability of red ball is **0.3**. I need the probability of pulling out 3 blue balls and one red ball (I always return the ball back inside). I have 4 options:

B B B R

B B R B

B R B B

R B B B

So my probability is **4 x (0.5)(0.5)
(0.5)(0.3**) I guess. My question is how can I find the number of options 4 in case it is too big and I can't find it just by listing my options. C might help cause 4c3 gives 4 and also 4c2 gives 6 which is correct but I don't know why.

Thank you!

Comment: The factor $\binom{n}{k}$ accounts for the number of ways exactly $k$ of the $n$ positions can be filled with a ball of a particular color.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the number of arrangements for your problem by using this method.
To find the possible arrangements of n unique objects we use n!. However, if there is repetition like in this case, the number of arrangements are over estimated.

- -like in this case
- -4!=24
- -so we need to cancel the effect of different arrangements of the similar type characters by dividing them
- -like here we will divide 4! by 3! and 1!
- -so the effect of 3Bs is canceled hence -4!/3!=4
- The probabilty= 4 x (0.5)(0.5) (0.5)(0.3)
- -if consider another example like
- BBRR BRBR RRBB RBBR BRRB RBRB
- -this is verified by the formula 4!/(2!*2!)=6 arrangements
- as now there are two types

-Also, check out this link
[Similar Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424380/permutations-with-repeating-letters)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I have known the formula  $n! / k!(n-k)!$  I just had no clue what is does. Now I do.

Comment: Good for you @Ori David. Please mark the question as answered if you feel satisfied by the answer.