# How to calculate combination of word which contains duplicate letters?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If i calculate combination of word "ball" using below formula (consider r as 2, I am selecting 2 letters)

```
C(n,r)=n!/r!(n−r)!
```

which return me 6 but actual combination is 4{ba,bl,al,ll}

so can anyone tell me! how to find combination of word which contains duplicate letters?

Comment: Hint: if there are $n$ copies of the same letter $k$, then there are $n\choose 2$ ways to make the word "$kk$".

Comment: It depends on the specific examples you are looking at whether or not there is an easier approach... here, we just say we look for combinations from `bal` and then recognize that there is one additional combination we are interested in for a total of $\binom{3}{2}+1=3+1=4$.  For the more general problem, it can get quite tedious to write down a generic formula but I recommend stars-and-bars along with inclusion-exclusion

Comment: @JMoravitz there's generic way to solve this kind of duplication problem in permutation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424380/permutations-with-repeating-letters . don't we have for combination??

Comment: I already linked a duplicate above.  Check the duplicate and if you still need clarification then say so.  Further, the question you linked was where we looked at using *all* of the letters, not just some of them, which makes it a different question than yours.